# Getting top 5 records and its count per month

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using phpmyadmin.
I have a table call `malicioussite`. It include 2 column call `region` which contain ISO-3166-1 alpha-2 code such as GB, US and `adddate` contain the timestamp of it.

```
SELECT region, COUNT(*) AS total 
FROM malicioussite 
GROUP BY region
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 5
```

It gave me the top 5 record of my table and it's correct:

```
region total
JP      7
US      6
RU      5
CN      4
DE      3
```

And now i want to get the top 5 record and its count per month of last 6 months.

```
SELECT region, MONTH(adddate) as Month, count(*) as Total
FROM malicioussite
where adddate BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW()-INTERVAL 5 MONTH, '%Y-%m-01 00:00:00') AND DATE_FORMAT(LAST_DAY(NOW()), '%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59')
GROUP BY YEAR(adddate), MONTH(adddate), region
```

It gave me all of the region and the count per month of last 6 months.

```
region  Month  Total
  AQ      9      1
  AR     10      1
  KR     11      1
  GB     12      1
  HK     12      1
  JP     12      1
  US     12      1
  AS      1      1
  HK      1      1
  JP      1      2
  US      1      1
  CN      2      4
  DE      2      3
  JP      2      4
  RU      2      5
  US      2      4
```

It's partly correct but what i want is only the top 5 region's such as below:

```
region  Month  Total
 JP     12      1
 JP      1      2
 JP      2      4
 US     12      1
 US      1      1
 US      2      4
 RU      2      5
 CN      2      4
 DE      2      3
```

Is there any way that should solve my issue?

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've done all the work, just need to add a condition with subquery.

```
SELECT region, MONTH(adddate) as Month, count(*) as Total
FROM malicioussite
where adddate BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW()-INTERVAL 5 MONTH, '%Y-%m-01 00:00:00') 
AND DATE_FORMAT(LAST_DAY(NOW()), '%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59')  
AND region IN (SELECT region 
               FROM malicioussite 
               GROUP BY region
               ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 5)
GROUP BY YEAR(adddate), MONTH(adddate), region
```

Or with a join

```
SELECT m.region, MONTH(adddate) as Month, count(*) as Total
FROM malicioussite m
JOIN (SELECT region 
      FROM malicioussite 
      GROUP BY region
      ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 5) as top_reg
ON top_reg.region = m.region
where adddate BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW()-INTERVAL 5 MONTH, '%Y-%m-01 00:00:00') 
AND DATE_FORMAT(LAST_DAY(NOW()), '%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59')       
GROUP BY YEAR(adddate), MONTH(adddate), m.region
```

Comment: sorry mr bouletta, it shows  " #1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery' ", is there any other sql to solve it?